# duplicate entire line when only part of it selected

Tags: intellij-idea

In `eclipse` when only a fragment of the line is selected it is possible to duplicate the entire line. I found it more convinience than selecting nothing or the entire line especially when more than one line is selected (then I don't have to select all the tabs in the first line).
Is it possible to duplicate entire lines in intellij, and not just the selected area?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently no keymap for that by default but there is a shortcut called `Duplicate entire lines`.
In my `Mac Osx 10.5+` keymap I mapped it to `cmd+alt+shift+down/up`.
See more details here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154167